# TypeError: Object of type Mock is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, assert, assertion

I have the following test file in my code:

```
# Copyright 2017-2021 The Wazo Authors  (see the AUTHORS file)
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

import json
from hamcrest import assert_that, equal_to, has_entries
from mock import ANY, Mock, patch, sentinel as s
from wazo_auth.config import _DEFAULT_CONFIG
from wazo_auth.tests.test_http import HTTPAppTestCase

ADDRESS_NULL = {
    'line_1': None,
    'line_2': None,
    'city': None,
    'state': None,
    'country': None,
    'zip_code': None,
}
ADDRESS_EMPTY = {
    'line_1': '',
    'line_2': '',
    'city': '',
    'state': '',
    'country': '',
    'zip_code': '',
}


class TestTenantPost(HTTPAppTestCase):

    url = '/0.1/tenants'

    def setUp(self):
        config = dict(_DEFAULT_CONFIG)
        config['enabled_http_plugins']['tenants'] = True
        super().setUp(config)

    @patch('wazo_auth.plugins.http.tenants.http.TenantDetector')
    def test_invalid_posts(self, TenantDetector):
        TenantDetector.autodetect.return_value = Mock(uuid=s.tenant_uuid)

        invalid_datas = [
            ('name', {'name': 42, 'slug': 'abc'}),
            ('name', {'name': 100 * 'foobar', 'slug': 'abc'}),
            ('slug', {'slug': 'a-b'}),
            ('slug', {'slug': 'a b'}),
            ('slug', {'slug': False}),
            ('slug', {'slug': 0}),
        ]

        for field, invalid_data in invalid_datas:
            result = self.post(invalid_data)
            assert_that(result.status_code, equal_to(400), invalid_data)
            assert_that(
                result.json,
                has_entries(
                    error_id='invalid-data',
                    message=ANY,
                    resource='tenants',
                    details=has_entries(
                        field,
                        has_entries(constraint_id=ANY, constraint=ANY, message=ANY),
                    ),
                ),
                invalid_data,
            )

    @patch('wazo_auth.plugins.http.tenants.http.TenantDetector')
    def test_empty_tenant_addresses(self, TenantDetector):
        TenantDetector.autodetect.return_value = Mock(uuid=s.tenant_uuid)

        invalid_bodies = [
            ('address', {'address': dict(
                line_1='',
                line_2='',
                city='',
                state='',
                zip_code='',
                country='',
            )}),
            ('address', {'address': dict(
                line_1=None,
                line_2=None,
                city=None,
                state=None,
                zip_code=None,
                country=None,
            )}),
        ]

        for field, invalid_body in invalid_bodies:
            result = self.post(invalid_body)
            assert_that(result.status_code, equal_to(400), invalid_body)
            assert_that(
                result.json,
                has_entries(
                    error_id='invalid-data',
                    message='Invalid tenant address length',
                    resource='tenants',
                    details=has_entries(
                        field,
                        has_entries(
                            constraint_id='length', constraint=ANY, message=ANY
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                invalid_body,
            )

    @patch('wazo_auth.plugins.http.tenants.http.TenantDetector')
    def test_that_validated_args_are_passed_to_the_service(self, TenantDetector):
        TenantDetector.autodetect.return_value = Mock(uuid=s.tenant_uuid)

        body = {'name': 'foobar', 'slug': 'slug', 'ignored': True}
        self.tenant_service.new.return_value = {
            'name': 'foobar',
            'uuid': '022035fe-f5e5-4c16-bd5f-8fea8f4c9d08',
        }

        result = self.post(body)

        assert_that(result.status_code, equal_to(200))
        assert_that(result.json, equal_to(self.tenant_service.new.return_value))
        self.tenant_service.new.assert_called_once_with(
            uuid=None,
            name='foobar',
            slug='slug',
            phone=None,
            contact_uuid=None,
            parent_uuid=s.tenant_uuid,
            address=dict(
                line_1=None,
                line_2=None,
                city=None,
                state=None,
                zip_code=None,
                country=None,
            ),
        )

    def post(self, data):
        return self.app.post(self.url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=self.headers)
```

When i defined the test function above `test_empty_tenant_addresses`, I get the following failure:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________ TestTenantPost.test_empty_tenant_addresses __________________

self = <wazo_auth.plugins.http.tenants.tests.test_tenants.TestTenantPost testMethod=test_empty_tenant_addresses>
TenantDetector = <MagicMock name='TenantDetector' id='140628422384888'>

    @patch('wazo_auth.plugins.http.tenants.http.TenantDetector')
    def test_empty_tenant_addresses(self, TenantDetector):
        TenantDetector.autodetect.return_value = Mock(uuid=s.tenant_uuid)
    
        invalid_bodies = [
            ('address', {'address': dict(
                line_1='',
                line_2='',
                city='',
                state='',
                zip_code='',
                country='',
            )}),
            ('address', {'address': dict(
                line_1=None,
                line_2=None,
                city=None,
                state=None,
                zip_code=None,
                country=None,
            )}),
        ]
    
        for field, invalid_body in invalid_bodies:
            result = self.post(invalid_body)
>           assert_that(result.status_code, equal_to(400), invalid_body)
E           AssertionError: {'address': {'line_1': '', 'line_2': '', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'zip_code': '', 'country': ''}}
E           Expected: <400>
E                but: was <500>

wazo_auth/plugins/http/tenants/tests/test_tenants.py:92: AssertionError
------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
ERROR    flask.app:app.py:1761 Exception on /0.1/tenants [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/wazo-auth/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/wazo-auth/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/root/wazo-auth/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 462, in wrapper
    return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
  File "/root/wazo-auth/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 491, in make_response
    resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/wazo-auth/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/representations/json.py", line 21, in output_json
    dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Mock is not JSON serializable
```

Apparently, the failure is caused by this line in my added function:

```
>           assert_that(result.status_code, equal_to(400), invalid_body)
```

which gives the following error message:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Mock is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried some solutions that I found by searching/looking for the issue, but I could not fix the issue. Please help me fix it, thanks.

P.S: The original code is in the following github repository:

https://github.com/wazo-platform/wazo-auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue as me, I found the solution by changing my dictionary declaration as below:

```
invalid_bodies = [
            ('address', {'address':
                'line_1':'',
                'line_2':'',
                'city':'',
                'state':'',
                'zip_code':'',
                'country':'',
           }),

        ]
```

I found the solution by logging both the input and the expected assertion output; and I noticed that the assertion failed because it was expecting an `OrderedDict` object instead of a `dictionary`.

Apparently, declaring your dictionary using the python keyworkd `dict` is not accepted (not JSON serializable; it converts it to `OrderedDict` type). Also, I removed the second body that I had (dictionary with `None` address fields).

Comment: found the solution by logging both the input and the expected assertion output, 
can you please give an example of how you did that?
I've the same error, but can't find which object causing it.