# How to serialize a Mock object?

Tags: python, json, serialization, python-unittest.mock

In my unit-tests there are some (nested) [`unittest.mock.Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) objects.

At some point, these `Mock` objects need to be serialized using [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

As expected, this raises a

```
TypeError: Object of type Mock is not JSON serializable
```

There are many questions and answers on SO about making classes serializable. For example, there's [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3768895), but this does not provide an answer specific to `Mock` objects. The titles for [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73989150) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70764110) look promising, but these do not provide an answer either.

The obvious thing to do is use the `default` argument, as in

```py
json.dumps(my_mock_object, default=mock_to_dict)
```

The question is, what is the easiest way to implement `mock_to_dict()`?

The serialized result should only include custom attributes, so `Mock` internals should be disregarded.

The following implementation appears to do the job for simple cases

```py
def mock_to_dict(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Mock):
        # recursive case
        return {
            key: mock_to_dict(value)
            for key, value in vars(obj).items()
            if not key.startswith('_') and key != 'method_calls'
        }
    # base case
    return obj
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?